# R calculate and add delta of two dataframe cells for each row

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
   df <- data.frame(
    "Subject" = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"),
    "Stage" = c( "pre", "pre", "pre", "post", "post", "post"), 
    "Value" = c(.5, .2, .7, 1, .8, .3)
)
```

I want to find the delta between `pre` and `post` columns for each row, something like:

```
delta <- df[df$Stage == 'post' & df$Subject == 'A', ] - df[df$Stage == 'pre' & df$Subject == 'B', ]
```

and then add it to its own column of the data frame:

```
df[["delt"]] <- NA
df[df$Subject == 'A', ][["delta"]] <- delta
```

The above works, but when I try to do it to all the rows with this method:

```
subjects <- unique(df$Subjects)
df[["delt"]] <- NA
calc_deltas <- function(position) {
   subject <- subjects[position]
   delta <- df[df$Stage == 'post' & df$Subject == subject, ] - df[df$Stage == 'pre' & df$Subject == subject, ]
   df[df$Subject == subject, ][["delta"]]
}
lapply(1:length(subjects), calc_deltas)
```

I expect the results to come out like this:

```
  Subject Stage Value delta
1       A   pre   0.5   0.5
2       B   pre   0.2   0.6
3       C   pre   0.7   -0.4
4       A  post   1.0   0.5
5       B  post   0.8   0.6
6       C  post   0.3   -0.4
```

But instead they come out like this:

```
  Subject Stage Value delta
1       A   pre   0.5   NA
2       B   pre   0.2   NA
3       C   pre   0.7   NA
4       A  post   1.0   NA
5       B  post   0.8   NA
6       C  post   0.3   NA
```

The rows remain as NA values.

My problem is complicated by the fact that I want to do that over multiple groups of observations within each row, I want to add the columns dynamically (I want to use the script for sets of data that, while fundamentally the same, have different groups). Here's the function from my script:

```
find_deltas <- function(pre_post_survey_data, question_groups) {
  output <- pre_post_survey_data

  users <- unique(output$username)

  calc_deltas <- function (position, name) {
    user <- users[position]
    calc_col_name <- paste0(name, "_mean")
    save_col_name <- paste0(name, "_delta")

    output[output$username == user, ][[save_col_name]] <- output[output$Step == 'post' & output$username == user, ][[calc_col_name]] - output[output$Step == 'pre' & output$username == user, ][[calc_col_name]]
    print(output[output$username == user, ][[save_col_name]])
  }

  for (name in names(question_groups)) {
    output[[paste0(name, "_delta")]] <- NA
    lapply(1:length(users), calc_deltas, name)  
  }

  output[["total_delta"]] <- NA
  lapply(1:length(users), calc_deltas, 'total')  

  output
}
```

The output in this case looks like this right now (the added delta columns are at the far right, the values are all NA, they ought to be calculated values) (this is example data, and doesn't actually add up as it should, refer to above example for that):

```
+---------+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-------------+
| Subject | Stage | qGroupA.1 | qGroupA.2 | qGroupA.3 | qGroupB.1 | qGroupB.2 | qGroupB.3 | qGroupB.4 | qGroupC.1 | qGroupC.2 | qGroupC.3 | qGroupC.4 | qGroupC.5 | qGroupA_mean | qGroupB_mean | qGroupC_mean | total_mean  | qGroupA_delta | qGroupB_delta | qGroupC_delta | total_delta |
+---------+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-------------+
| A       | pre   | 0.666     | 0.333     | NA        | 1         | 0.666     | 0.666     | 1         | 1         | 1         | 1         | 0.666     | 1         | 0.4995       | 0.833        | 0.9332       | 0.897037394 | NA            | NA            | NA            | NA          |
| B       | pre   | NA        | 0.333     | 0.333     | 0.666     | 0.666     | 0.666     | 0.666     | 0.666     | 0.666     | 0.666     | 0.666     | 0.666     | 0.333        | 0.666        | 0.666        | 0.575108097 | NA            | NA            | NA            | NA          |
| A       | post  | 0.666     | 0.333     | 0.333     | 0.666     | 0.666     | 1         | 0.666     | 1         | 1         | 1         | 1         | 1         | 0.444        | 0.7495       | 1            | 0.897037394 | NA            | NA            | NA            | NA          |
| B       | post  | 0.666     | NA        | 0.333     | 1         | 0         | 1         | 1         | 1         | 0.666     | 0.666     | 1         | 1         | 0.4995       | 0.75         | 0.8664       | 0.575108097 | NA            | NA            | NA            | NA          |
+---------+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-------------+
```

Why am I not able to add the values to the dataframe within the lapply function? Is there another, more straight forward way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Can you show expected output please?

Comment: ah yes, I knew I was forgetting something!

Comment: For the original with `dplyr`, something like `df %>% group_by(Subject) %>% mutate(delta = Value[2] - Value[1])`. You could probably use `mutate_each` for the bigger case, but it may be simpler to melt to long and group more.

Comment: Okay, I've not used dplyer or reshape2 (that's where melt comes from, yes?). I guess, once I melt to long, I'd do my calculations, add each calculation as to a row with the name_delta as the variable, then melt it back to wide? (going by examples here: http://seananderson.ca/2013/10/19/reshape.html)

Comment: Pretty much. [`tidyr`](https://github.com/hadley/tidyr) is the successor to `reshape2`; you're looking for `gather` to melt.

Comment: I messed up in my placement of the examples... apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general approach to this sort of problems is the so called split-apply-combine strategy.  Using R base functions `split`, `lapply` and `unsplit` you could do for instance:

```
> df.1 <- split(df, df$Subject)
> df.2 <- lapply(df.1, function(x)
+     within(x, delta <- diff(setNames(Value, Stage)[c('post', 'pre')])))
> df.3 <- unsplit(df.2, df$Subject)
> df.3
  Subject Stage Value delta
1       A   pre   0.5  -0.5
2       B   pre   0.2  -0.6
3       C   pre   0.7   0.4
4       A  post   1.0  -0.5
5       B  post   0.8  -0.6
6       C  post   0.3   0.4
```

You can combine the three steps into one, if you want.

Comment: This looks like the solution I'll go with, I like that it doesn't require additional libraries. Thanks for introducing me to the 'within' function (and by proxy, the 'with' function) -- that will save me a lot of typing. I'm a little confused with how setNames is working within the diff function and I'm not sure how to unpack it and see them working together in a simpler context. Can you point me to an example?

Comment: `setNames` returns the vector `Value` with the "names" attribute set to `Stage`. I do this so I can index `Value` using a character vector. Without the names attribute set it wouldn't work. Try: `x <- 1:2; y <- c('a','b'); z <- setNames(x, y)` and see how `x[c('a','a','b')]` fails and `z[c('a','a','b')]` works. To set the names attribute in place you can do `attr(x, 'names') <- y` or `names(x) <- y`.

Comment: Ah, I see. But how can I set the name "delta" dynamically -- if you look in my question, I'm trying to loop through a set of question groups to find the deltas for each group, I don't want to explicitly list out each name, I'd like to just loop through them. `save_col_name <- paste0(name, "_delta")` if I use that as so: `within(x, save_col_name <- ... ` the column it creates is called save_col_name, if I try something like this: `within(x, x[[save_col_name]] <- ... ` then `x.<all-of-my-columns>` are duplicated and added to the dataframe.

Comment: hmm, I could do it within my lapply function, just rename the column as a separate step... is there a way to do it inline?

Comment: Replace `delta <- x` with `assign(y, x)` where `y` is a variable with the name you want to assign `x` to. But if you do this the `unsplit` operation will fail, I think.

Comment: I just renamed it within the lapply function. It works -- thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not very clear on what you want, here is a try using `dplyr`.

```
df <- data.frame(
  "Subject" = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"),
  "Stage" = c( "pre", "pre", "pre", "post", "post", "post"), 
  "Value" = c(.5, .2, .7, 1, .8, .3)
)
```

Using the above dataset, only trying to populate the `delta` column, my approach would be:

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
df %>%
  dcast(., Subject ~ Stage, value.var = "Value") %>%
  mutate(delta = post-pre)

  Subject post pre delta
1       A  1.0 0.5   0.5
2       B  0.8 0.2   0.6
3       C  0.3 0.7  -0.4
```

However, if you do want the `long` format:

```
df %>%
  dcast(., Subject ~ Stage, value.var = "Value") %>%
  mutate(delta = post-pre) %>%
  melt(., id.vars = c('Subject','delta'), variable.name = "Stage", value.name = "Value")

  Subject delta Stage Value
1       A   0.5  post   1.0
2       B   0.6  post   0.8
3       C  -0.4  post   0.3
4       A   0.5   pre   0.5
5       B   0.6   pre   0.2
6       C  -0.4   pre   0.7
```

This approach will work for any number of variables, and you can add more columns using the `mutate` functionality of `dplyr`.